# How to avoid mentioning a function pointer's arguments inside the definition of a function that takes it as argument?

Tags: c, prototype, function-pointers, obsolete, c23

I'm writing this C code that involves passing around a lot of function pointers, and sometimes writing all the arguments that a function pointer takes when defining a function that takes it as an argument can significantly increase the length of the function definition and thus decrease its readability. For instance, say I have this function `foo` that takes three `int`s and a function pointer to perform a certain operation. The typical way to declare a function like `foo` is something along the lines of:

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c, int (*operation) (int, int, int));
```

I was wondering  if there was a way to avoid the redundancy of having to re-mention the variable types  another time in the type of the function pointer.

An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75305328/in-c-can-you-omit-the-parameter-types-of-a-function-pointer-when-initializing-i) suggests that it is possible to only use empty parentheses `()` , which translates in the above example to:

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c, int (*operation) ());
```

However, a comment to the same post states that this kind of syntax is going to be removed in C23:

> As a side note, this is obsolescent C since year 1989. Empty
> parenthesis () no prototype style should not be used. And it will
> finally get removed in upcoming C23

Comment: Use a `typedef`.

Comment: @KamilCuk In this example maybe, but imagine if `operation` also took a function pointer as an argument. This is the kind of stuff I'm dealing with mostly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038430/how-to-create-a-typedef-for-function-pointers

Comment: Actually, in C23 a function declared with an empty parameter type list is the same as a function declared with a parameter type list consisting solely of the keyword `void`, i.e. in C23, `int foo()` and `int foo(void)` are the same. This is a deviation from previous versions of the C standard in the case where the function declarator is not part of a function definition.

Comment: @IanAbbott So it will not be removed, just have its behaviour/meaning change?

Comment: Yes, its behavior/meaning will be aligned with C++. In current (pre-C23), `int foo();` declares a function with no information about parameters, but in C23 is will declare a function with no parameters (same as `int foo(void);`). In a function definition, `int foo() { return 42; }` is the same as `int foo(void) { return 42; }` in both pre-C23 and C23.

Comment: Also, pre-C23, `int foo();` and `int foo(int, int, int);` are compatible with each other, but in C23 they will no longer be compatible with each other.

Comment: The correct solution before or after C23 is to always use `typedef` for all function pointer types.

Comment: @Lundin What's wrong with the solution that uses empty parentheses to declare a function pointer prior to C23?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, just make an alias. I like function aliases over function pointer aliases, so that I know it's a pointer.

```
typedef int operation_t(int, int, int);
int foo(int a, int b, int c, operation_t *operation);
```